# Is there a way in Xcode to remove all references that cannot be located anymore?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, reference

I recently removed images that are not referenced any more from sources. Since these images are so many, I have deleted them outside the Xcode, with customized shell script.

Now for the remaining references - is there a way to instantly remove them in Xcode, other than repeatedly selecting them and pressing delete key?

Comment: Well this isn't an automatic solution, but you can hold cmd and select multiple files for deletion at once.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I need to know something other than manually deleting them.